# Hide a Part (document) in Autodesk Inventor

Tags: c#, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I am using **Autodesk Inventor Proffessional 2015** and the **C# SDK API**. I am able to hide a full `AssemblyDocument` by traversing the `ComponentOccurrences`:

```
foreach ( var occurrence in _assemblyDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences )
                    ( (ComponentOccurrence) occurrence ).Visible = false;
```

but this method does not work using a `PartDocument`. How can I hide a Part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was that it is not possible to hide a document per se, but rather all the occurrences of the document in the assembly.